# Nginx proxy_pass part of url and params

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, http-proxy

I need to proxy request
From my server to another
Two options should be realized

First:

From https://my-site.com/subjects/custom_id to https://another-site.com/subjects/custom_id

Example:

https://my-site.com/subjects/1 to https://another-site.com/subjects/1

https://my-site.com/subjects/2 to https://another-site.com/subjects/2

Nginx config  (works fine):

```
  location ~ ^/subjects/?(.*) {
     resolver 8.8.8.8;
     proxy_pass https://another-site.com/subjects/$1$is_args$args;
   }
```

Second:

From  https://my-site.com/subjects?code=custom_code to  https://another-site.com/subjects?code=custom_code

Example:

https://my-site.com/subjects?code=1 to https://another-site.com/subjects?code=1

https://my-site.com/subjects?code=2 to https://another-site.com/subjects?code=2

How to write Nginx config for this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
location ^~ /subjects {
     resolver 8.8.8.8;
     proxy_pass https://another-site.com/subjects;
}
```